# Rally SDK 2 - How to attach a story to a feature

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I try to write a custom HTML block using Rally SDK 2.1 (Javascript) in order to create a new story. I can figure how to create the story with a custom title and description.

If I try to set the feature, then the creation hangs and nothing happens...
Here is how I set the feature ine the script:

```html
      var story = Ext.create(model, {
       Name: 'Can be deleted, created via Rally app SDK 2.1',
       Description: 'Dummy generated story - tests',
       PortfolioItem: '/portfolioitem/featureset/12345' // FEATURE
      });
```

If I remove the "PortfolioItem" attribute, then it works like a charm.

Here is my global script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test - Story creation</title>
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.1/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
  
  // SDK documentation: https://docs.ca.com/en-us/ca-agile-central/saas/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api
    
        Rally.onReady(function() {
     
   // Create a new story
   function addStory() {  
   
    console.log('Creating a new story...');
    // Retrieve the Rally user stories model
    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
     type: 'UserStory',
     context: {
      workspace: '/workspace/12345', // dummy reference
      project: '/project/12345' // dummy reference
     },
     success: function(model) {
      // Create a new story thanks to the retrieved model
      var story = Ext.create(model, {
       Name: 'Can be deleted, created via Rally app SDK 2.1',
       Description: 'Dummy generated story - tests',
       PortfolioItem: '/portfolioitem/featureset/12345' // dummy reference
      });
      // Save the new story
      story.save({
       callback: function(result, operation) {
        if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
         console.log('New story created!', result.get('FormattedID'));
        }
       }
      });
     }
    });
   }
   
   // The Rally application
   Ext.define('Rally.grg.storyCreation', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    
    // Method fired on application launch
    // Retrieve release features asynchronously
    launch: function() {
     console.log('Launch...');
     addStory();  
    }     
   });   
      
            Rally.launchApp('Rally.grg.storyCreation', {
              name: 'test - Story creation'
            }); 

        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I tried to declare a new portfolioitem object that would reference the feature I want. Then I reference it at story level, but it behaves exactly the same:

```html
    var f; 
   
    console.log('Defining the feature...');
    // Retrieve the Rally features model
    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
     type: 'portfolioitem',
     success: function(portfolioitemkModel) {
      // Define an existing feature thanks to the retrieved model
      f = Ext.create(portfolioitemkModel, {
       _ref: "/portfolioitem/featureset/12345",
       _refObjectName: "...",
       _refObjectUUID: "...",
       _type: "PortfolioItem/FeatureSet"       
      });
     }
    });
```

As someone an example of linking a story and its parent feature trought JavaScript SDK2, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try changing this line:

```
PortfolioItem: '/portfolioitem/featureset/12345'
```

to this:

```
PortfolioItem: '/portfolioitem/feature/12345'
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion JPKole, but it does not work better.

Comment: I used the exact code above, replacing only the ObjectID (12345) of the Workspace, Project and Feature, as well as changing 'featureset' to 'feature'.  It then successfully created a story which was linked to my feature.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! It works!
I tried with another feature and it works great. I don't understand why but it does not work with all features, maybe some restriction/privileges.